# Convert Dropdown menu to vertical

Tags: css, menu

I have a drop down menu with css file and i want to convert it into Verctical menu I tried much but i can do that please anyone help me Folowing is my css and html code.anyone please tell me what exactly i am missing due to which menu is not converting

```
#sddmT
{   margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 30}

#sddmT li
{   margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    font: bold 11px arial}

#sddmT li a
{   display: block;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #4A617B;
    color: White;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none}

#sddmT li a:hover
{   background: #BDCFD6;
    color:#4A617B

    }

#sddmT div
{   position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #4A617B;
    border: 1px solid #BDCFD6}

    #sddmT div a
    {   position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        width: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: left;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #4A617B;
        color: #BDCFD6;
        font: 11px arial}

    #sddmT div a:hover
    {   background: #BDCFD6;
        color:  #4A617B}
```

And her is html Code

```
 <ul id="sddm">
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m1')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">ETP</a>
       <div id="m1"  onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()"  onclick="mclosetime()">
        <a href="http://dashboard.shakarganj.com.pk/ca/sml1etp.php" target=_blank>ETP - Jhang</a>
        <a href="http://dashboard.shakarganj.com.pk/ca/sml2etp.php" target=_blank>ETP - Bhone</a>
        </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And here is my JS code to clos and open the menu items

```
<!--
var timeout         = 500;
var closetimer      = 0;
var ddmenuitem      = 0;

// open hidden layer
function mopen(id)
{   
    // cancel close timer
    mcancelclosetime();

    // close old layer
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    // get new layer and show it
    ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
    ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';

}
// close showed layer
function mclose()
{
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

// go close timer
function mclosetime()
{
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(mclose, timeout);
}

// cancel close timer
function mcancelclosetime()
{
    if(closetimer)
    {
        window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;
    }
}

// close layer when click-out
//document.onclick = mclose; 
// -->
```

**upDate**
I want like this
[image]

Comment: any one please answer to my question

Comment: do you want this : http://jsfiddle.net/Z8jpD/1

Comment: could you please describe how the vertical menu will look like?

Comment: But Why IT Remained Opened I want to open the submenu won mouover but these are not please tell some more idea

Comment: your javascript for open and close menu didn't work on my page when I try to apply it, so I'm not clear what to achieve, but on my guess, please try to remove the float:left from #sddmT li, then try to apply into #sddmT ul li{float:left;}

Comment: yes its works but submenues are opening on same position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> #sddmT li {   margin: 0;
>       padding: 0;
>       list-style: none;
>       position:static;
>       font: bold 11px arial; }

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I couldn't help noticing you have some whitespace between your main and sub-menus. Wrapping the submenus with the item that they point to will work, but you need to eliminate the whitespace, or you'll trigger the close/exit function every time you go to open the menu.

`margin: 0 1px 0 0` vs `margin:0`.